# Java HashMap remove item after its hash changed

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a `HashMap` where keys are mutable complex objects - hash changes over their lifetime. I know exactly what objects are changed, but only after the fact - their removal using `map.remove(object)` will not work because the hash changed. Number of objects in the map is about in range [10, 10 000], the issue is rather in number of changes and accesses.

It would be demanding to do a "would you change" check on each object before changing it - double the work, not to mention the mess of a code necessary for it.

I do iterate entries in the map later on, so I figured I could simply mark objects for removal and get rid of them using `iterator.remove()`, but unfortunately `HashMap$HashIterator#remove` calls `hash(key)`.

The one option that comes to my mind is to throw away the original map and rehash all objects that are not marked for removal into a new map, but that would generate a lot of extra time and memory garbage - would like to avoid it.

Another option would be writing my own HashMap that keeps track of where exactly is stored every element (say map formed by 2D object array = two int coordinates). This would be more efficient, but also a lot more to write and test.

Is there any easier way to do this that I have missed?

**Edit:**

I use wrappers over the complex object that supply different hash/equals pairs depending on subset of properties. Each object may be in multiple maps. Say I look for *red* object in map that uses wrappers with hash/equals over color, create *red* dummy object, and do map.get(dummy).

Implementations of hash/equals and specific properties they touch are not part of my code.

All maps are objects mapped onto themselves (like Set implementation, but I do need map access methods). I can store hashes in those wrappers, and then they will adhere to the contract from hash perspective, but equals will still fail me.

I do understand that by changing hash/equals output is undefined behavior, but it really should not matter in theory - I change object, and then I do not want to use the map until the changed object is gone from it. Hash map should not really need to call equals() or hash() for object it is already pointing at with iterator.

Comment: **Do not change properties that contribute to the `hashCode` whilst an object is in a `HashMap`.** Sorry. It's just that simple. Your question amounts to "I'm carrying out a task that is UB. Please define the behaviour." This is simply not possible. You could, for example, use a wrapper.

Comment: You can add synthetic property like `uniqueId` to every object you use as key and use that property in `hashCode()` so changing other properties of object will not affect hash

Comment: is your hashmap local or global? Are the entities persistent or what's their lifecycle? I am with @BoristheSpider, do not change the values until your job with hashmap is done. Either use immutable ID for hashcode, use wrappers, make copies during the job

Comment: How do you want to retrieve an object from a `Map` when you modified its key? Either you have to remove the object from the `Map` before you modify the key and store it back afterwards, or `Map` is not the right `Collection` for your purpose; think about `List` instead …

Comment: UB - Undefined Behaviour

Comment: Added info in edit. @Ivan it is not possible to do unique ID mapping, the domain is too big.

Comment: @fairtrax hashmaps are only for acceleration of the same process I do over arrays when number of elements is small.

Comment: @tquadrat removal before change is quite complicated, and list is being accelerated by the map - I need constant access time when looking for object with specific property subset.

Comment: Extend ConcurrentHashMap and add a background job that periodically crawls the keyset and eliminates items that are no longer bucketed correctly.

Comment: Not possible. You have corrupted the map. Solution: don't.

Comment: @user207421 how is "don't" a solution. I have a problem that I attempted solving using HashMap. You can say that there is no way of adapting HashMap so it works, fair, but that is not solution, you just telling me what isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previous state:

User supplies equals/hash lambdas that work over complex object to place it each map in correct place (looking up objects of similar properties in constant time).

Complex object did change in inconvenient times causing issues with reinsert - object changes, pull it out, return it with new hash.

Current solution:

In theory could be solved with custom implementation of hash map (note NOT hash map interface, would not uphold its contract). This map would cache hashes for its contents for rehash purposes, and maintain coordinates in underlying structure so equals is not necessary for removal with values iterator. May implement it later to reduce memory footprint.

Used solution was forcing user to supply key that wraps all used properties and adds hash/equals that considers those properties. Now even though complex object changes, its key stays the same until prompted for update (not inside of the map at the time of the update).

```
public class Node {
    public HashMap<Key, Node> map;
    public Data<T> data;
    public Key key;
    public Node parent;
    public void update() {
        if (parent != null) parent.map.remove(key);
        key.update(data);
        if (parent != null) parent.map.put(key, this);
    }
}

public abstract class Key {
    public abstract void update(Data data);
    public abstract int hashCode();
    public abstract boolean equals(Object obj);
}

public class MyKey extends Key {

    private Object value = null;

    public final void update(Data data) {
        value = data.value;
    }

    public final boolean equals(Object obj) {
        IdentityKey that = (IdentityKey)obj;
        return this.value == that.value;
    }

    public final int hashCode() {
        return value == null ? 0 : value.hashCode();
    }
}
```

This requires a lot of primitive Key implementations, but at least it works. Will probably look for something better.

Answer (score 0):

> All maps are objects mapped onto themselves (like Set implementation, but I do need map access methods). I can store hashes in those wrappers, and then they will adhere to the contract from hash perspective, but equals will still fail me.

As others said, either try to find an immutable key (e.g. generated or a subset of some immutable properties) or have a look at other data structures, are some of the general recommendations witout seeing the code.

I didn't quite understand why you can "store hashes in those wrappers" but still have trouble with the equals method. (I guess the stored hashes would no be unique so they could be checked in the equals method?)

But if you have immutable hashes and if you have only one instance per "equal" object (not one instance stored in the map and another but equal instance used for lookup), you could have a look at the [IdentityHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html) class.